# Can i apply .On() with jquery .Hide() to be able to hide newly added content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on a web application, and i want to remove all the `<a>` that have the word "question". so i write the following script:-

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('a.ms-pivotControl-surfacedOpt:contains("question")').hide();
});
</script>
```

Now i got this behavioure:-

1. when the page first loads, the script will be able to hide all the content correctly.
2. but if i click on a button that will refresh the page in an Ajax-Based approach, then the content that have "Questions" inside it will be shown (the script will not have any effect).

so i think the problem is that the script will not be able to understand the newly added content. i remember on old jquery versions i use to define `.Live()` to keep my script live and to understand newly added content ,, so is this possible inside my above script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on()` and the deprecated `live()` are only for event delegation, not for DOM manipulation or plugin initializing.

When you need to manipulate newly inserted html , or initialize a plugin on it, there is no way to delegate that and you need to use the callback of ajax to do it.

Example using simplest ajax method `load()`

```
$('#container').load('somefile.html',function(){
   // new html exists, "this" is initial selector element
   $(this).find('.someClass').hide();    
});
```

Comment: but in my case i can not access the ajax call back as this is a third part web application ,, so i can not access the ajax call back in any way... so is there any other approach that i can follow?

Comment: @johnG, that third party web application must be included in your source somehow. If its cdn, then get the code, change it, and include it in your application

Comment: @AmmarCSE that's not always the case such as a simple script tag that loads another script

Comment: @AmmarCSE this is a sharepoint web application,, so not sure if this is exposed to me ...

Comment: @johnG worst case can set up an interval timer to check for those elements and then clearInterval. Need more details on how 3rd party behaves

Comment: @charlietfl, ah, good point. Maybe this would help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Answer (score 1):

In your success handler of ajax add this line after your processing :

```
 $('a.ms-pivotControl-surfacedOpt:contains("question")').hide();
```

Comment: i do not own and i can not access the ajax call back as this is a third party solution. i can only write script against what is already provided...

Comment: how about using this : www.api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/  a little raw though as it will subscribe to all ajax requests of your page..